# Undefined variable error in EXCEPTION block | BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I declare a variable that can also be referenced in EXCEPTION block in BigQuery stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test.my_sp_1()
BEGIN
  DECLARE var1 INT64 DEFAULT 1;
  SELECT 1/0;
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
  SELECT var1;
END;
```

when the sp is invoked, I'm getting below error

> Query error: Unrecognized name: var1 at [my-project.test.my_sp_1:5:10]

Is it possible to reference a variable declared above exception block?

Comment: *Variables declared in a BEGIN block are valid only in the BEGIN section, and may not be used in the block’s exception handler.*   see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#beginexceptionend

Comment: @Jaytiger, what if must use the defined variable in EXCEPTION block, and bigquery doesn't allow that, should we consider that a flaw?

Comment: I've added a workaround. kindly check that if it can be applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery script seems to support *block-level* variable scope and *EXCEPTION* seems to start a new block of statements. If so, you are not accessible to a variable defined in same level of another block scope in the script.

> what if must use the defined variable in EXCEPTION block,

If you have to access a pre-defined variable in EXCEPTION block, I think you can declare it in outer block and access it inner EXCEPTION block like below.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fn.my_sp_1()
BEGIN -- outer block
  DECLARE var1 INT64 DEFAULT 1;  -- a variable defined in outer block
  BEGIN -- initiates a new block
    SELECT 1/0; -- exception occurs
  EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
    SELECT var1; -- you can access a variable defined in outer block scope here.
  END;
END;

CALL fn.my_sp_1();
```

**Query results**

[image]

**References**

- [BEGIN..END](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#begin)

  > `BEGIN` initiates a block of statements where declared variables exist only until the corresponding `END`.